# android:textSize change in MotionLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-motionlayout

I am going to animate text size change using MotionLayout.

I do the following for start state

```
<CustomAttribute
    motion:attributeName="textSize"
    motion:customDimension="16sp" />
```

And the following for end state

```
<CustomAttribute
    motion:attributeName="textSize"
    motion:customDimension="14sp" />
```

As a result, it looks like size is actually changing, but it's much larger than 14sp-16sp

So, how to change text size properly?

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53603009/how-can-i-scale-textview-inside-parent-view-with-motion-layout

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
<CustomAttribute
    motion:attributeName="textSize"
    motion:customFloatValue="14" />
```

Comment: Will it be a size in sp, not in physical pixels?

Comment: Sorry if you use this you can't pass values in sp or pixel, you have pass values in float.

Answer (score 8):

Try animating *font size* using **scale** attribute as it is **Double** type instead of  **textSize (Integer)**. Animation will be cleaner because Double scales smoother.

```
<ConstraintSet 
        android:id="@id/start">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@id/element"   
        android:scaleX="1.0"
        android:scaleY="1.0"/>
</ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet
        android:id="@id/end">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@id/element"   
        android:scaleX="0.5"
        android:scaleY="0.5"/>
</ConstraintSet>
```

Comment: This solution is much more reliable than animating `textSize`. First of all text size values set with `setTextSize` don't match those set with `android:textSize`. Secondly, by setting `android:transformPivotX` and `android:transformPivotY`, you can place text scaling pivot where you need it.

Comment: glad you shared this approach, the other ans like using **motion:customFloatValue** gave a weird flicker and some alphabets goes missing during transition if i make fast up and down drag

Comment: Scale doesn't affect the layout, including the size of `wrap_content` `MotionLayout`.

Answer (score 5):

The above answer is correct. Because it is a `CustomAttribute` with the value as `customFloatValue`, you must pass in a float, not a scalable pixel dimension.

However, the custom attribute `textSize` when used on a `TextView` simply calls `setTextSize` which as you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize(float)) interprets the float given as a scalable type so it will set it to `sp` automatically! Tada!

Answer (score 0):

Use "motion:customDimension" for change textSize. Below file is **scene.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        motion:duration="2000">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragDown"
            motion:moveWhenScrollAtTop="true"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="bottom"
            motion:touchRegionId="@+id/ivExpand" />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">

    <Constraint
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="textSize"
                motion:customDimension="10sp" />

        </Constraint>

 </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
 <Constraint
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="textSize"
                motion:customDimension="5sp" />

        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>
```

Add **scene.xml** (scene description file) in mainActivity.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
</<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled at the same thing and managed to get it worked. If you are using motion editor, chances are the start constraintSet is based on the layout. You have to manually specify the textSize on the start constraintSet:

```
<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/tv_car_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_car"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
        <CustomAttribute
            app:attributeName="textSize"
            app:customFloatValue="30"/>
    </Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>
```

And finally, for the end constraintSet:

```
<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/tv_car_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_car"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
        <CustomAttribute
            app:attributeName="textSize"
            app:customFloatValue="15"/>
    </Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>
```