# How to animate a wrap_content TextView in MotionLayout?

Tags: android, textview, sticky, android-transitions, android-motionlayout

First of all, I have created a [minimal demo](https://github.com/siralam/MotionLayoutPlayground/tree/TextView-Width-Problem) to demonstrate the issue.

### What I want to do

I have 2 `TextView` on the top of my screen. The second one is on the right of the first one, with smaller size. Both display some content returned by API (So I don't know how long it needs to be - i.e. they have to be `wrap_content`.)

Now I want to implement a sticky header with transition effect: When user scrolls up, the first `TextView` will shrink to almost the same size with the second one, and keep themselves on the top of the screen. To achieve this, `MotionLayout` seems to be a perfect fit.

### My approach

Since I don't know the length of the content, so in order to animate the size of the first `TextView`, I can only choose one of the below:

1. Animate textSize
2. Animate scale

Approach 1 can be done by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58856800/7870874) solution. However, the animation is not smooth at all so it cannot be used.

So I tried approach 2. The `layoutDescription` file transit the first `TextView` from

```xml
        <Constraint
                android:id="@+id/tvFirst"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/vTop"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

to

```xml
        <Constraint
                android:id="@+id/tvFirst"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/vTop"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:transformPivotX="0dp"
                android:transformPivotY="0dp"
                android:scaleX="0.6"
                android:scaleY="0.6"/>
```

The animation effect is great, but

### The problem

The width of the `TextView` does not change. Only its content scaled down. The problem here is, I want the second `TextView` to stick to the end of the content, but now there is a large gap between them.

[image]

### What did I tried

I tried to combine 2 approaches. i.e. I created a transparent `TextView` as a dummy of the first `TextView`, which animates using approach 1 (TextSize), and let the second `TextView` constraint to the dummy instead. However, the width change occurs only after completing the transition, the second `TextView` still stays at the same location during the transition.

### My question

How can I animate it smoothly with the second `TextView` sticking to the end of the content of the first `TextView`?

Comment: Did you wrap the `TextView` in a `Constraint` layout? If so, does the layout shink as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a know problem with out a good solution.
By default MotionLayout Blocks relaying out during animation.
This can be changed by the flag Transition:

```
 <Transition     motion:layoutDuringTransition="honorRequest" \>
```

This then means the layout is being resolved at every pass (which is slow)  but might suit your needs.
Another approach would be to use MotionLabel which was designed to do smooth scaling.

Which is designed to mitigate the scaling quantization
with an attribute scaleFromTextSize

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.utils.widget.MotionLabel
    app:textPanX="0"
    app:scaleFromTextSize="40sp"
    android:textSize="90sp"/>
```

This grabs "outlines" of the text from size and scales them to the desired size.

Long term we are looking for better solutions for this problem.

Comment: `layoutDuringTransition="honorRequest"` is good enough for me. Thank you!

Comment: It's good to mention that "honorRequest" could have significant performance impact.